# Assign Attribute Value to Content of Element in XML (using XSD or XSL)

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I have a document that requires some titles to have standard names, while others are left up to the author. To distinguish the difference, I have created an attribute, "hardTitle". If the hardTitle attribute has a value, the title element should display the value of hardTitle and lock it from being edited. If the hardTitle attribute is empty, then the author can use whatever title they like.

I have tried using  with enumeration values (code below), but that will only tell me if the value is incorrect - it won't populate the value in the element nor will it lock the element content from being edited.

What I would like:

```
<chapter>
    <title hardTitle="Scope">Scope</title> [auto-populated from hardTitle and locked]
    ...
    <title>This Title Can Be Anything</title>
    ...
     <title hardTitle="NewT">NewT</title> [auto-populated from hardTitle and locked]
</chapter>
```

Here is the code I have so far. I know xs:restriction is restricting the text to the enumerated value...  but I am looking for something that will force the content based on the attribute and then lock it from editing.

.xsd file snippet:

```
<xs:element name="title" type="editableTitle">
        <xs:alternative test="if(@hardTitle)" type="lockedTitle" />
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="editableTitle">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="hardTitle" />
            </xs:extension> 
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="lockedTitle">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:restriction base="editableTitle">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="@hardTitle" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: XSD doesn't really support "locking", it'll just tell you if it's "invalid".  You probably need application programming for that sort of logic between attributes.

Comment: XSD also doesn't support modifying documents.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I'm just starting out with XML, and this has cleared things up for me regarding what I can and can't do with an XSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constraint can be *applied*, in the sense of converting an input document to a different document wherein that the constraint is satisfied, via this simple XSL transform:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="title[@hardTitle]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- supposes that <title> elements will not have child elements -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:value-of select="@hardTitle" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constraint can be expressed via an XSD 1.1 assertion on `title`,

```
<xs:assert test="not(@hardTitle) or . = @hardTitle"/>
```

which says that there must either be no `@hardTitle` attribute or the string value of `title` must equal the value of `@hardTitle`.

Your constraint cannot be expressed in XSD 1.0.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look and answer my question. I was able to use assert to test the value and prevent the file from validating - but I needed to take it a step further and try to apply the value of the attribute to the element itself.